# Firestore database won't appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new with Firebase and I'm still learning how it works. I've created a login, signup and logout sections. The users appear registrated and are saved in the authentication section, but I also want to have their data in database when they register for the first time. I thought of using Firestore Database. The problem is that everything seems to work, but nothing appears in my database section. At first I thought that I was not passing any user auth to the function, so i created a condition to test if there's no user auth, then show a warning. However, there's no warning so it means that I passed it properly.

This is how the sign up function works:

```
export const SignUp = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const displayName = useRef();
    const email = useRef();
    const password = useRef();
    const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (password.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
            return setError("Passwords do not match");
        }

        try {
            setError("")
            setLoading(true)
            const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.current.value, password.current.value)
            const userRef = await handleUserProfile(user, displayName.current.value)
            console.log(userRef)
        } catch {
            setError("Failed to create an account")
        }

        setLoading(false)
    }
```

I create the user with **auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword** and then I pass the user to **handleUserProfile**

Here's handleUserProfile function:

```
export const handleUserProfile = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
    if (!userAuth) {
        console.warn("No userAuth")
        return
    }

    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const timestamp = new Date()

    try {
        return await firestore.collection("users").add({
            displayName,
            email,
            timestamp,
            ...additionalData
        })

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

    return null;
};
```

Then, nothing appears in my database and nothing gets added. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `displayName.current.value` seems to be a string to me (or is it an object?) but you are trying to use spread operator `...additionalData` (which will be a string). Can you try removing `...`? Also check the console for any errors..

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thanks for comenting! But this doesn't solve my problem unfortunately

Comment: Can you `console.log(displayName, email, timestamp, additionalData)` before the `add()` method and share the output?

Comment: @Dharmaraj here's the output: john19@gmail.com Mon Aug 23 2021 11:30:58 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central) {displayName: "john"}

Comment: @ian12_Is your issue resolved?

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra No, it isn't unfortunately

Comment: You are not adding the data to a document in the collection. You have to do :  try {
        return await firestore.collection("users").doc().add({
            displayName,
            email,
            timestamp,
            ...additionalData
        }) Let me know if it worked.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The console shows a TypeError: "firestore.collection(...).doc(...).add is not a function"

Comment: Can you console.log(userAuth) and tell me the output.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra this is the output: john12@gmail.com Tue Sep 14 2021 20:04:15 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central) {displayName: 'John'}

Comment: The output you are showing is `console.log(userRef)` from `const userRef = await handleUserProfile(user, displayName.current.value); console.log(userRef)` in your code. Now "john12@gmail.com Tue Sep 14 2021 20:04:15 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central) " is {user} and {displayName: 'John'} is `displayName.current.value ` that you are passing as parameters to `handleUserProfile(user, displayName.current.value),`. Also in function definiton that equals userAuth, additionalData in `export const handleUserProfile = async (userAuth, additionalData)`.

Comment: try {
        `return await firestore.collection("users").add`({
            `displayName : ...additionalData,`
            `email: userAuth.email`
            `timestamp : new Date()`
      })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

Answer (score 0):

The `firestore.collections().add` function is adding objects (`key: value` pairs).

It looks like you're not passing an object into `handleUserProfile`:

```
const userRef = await handleUserProfile(user, displayName.current.value)
```

Passing an object into `additionalData` should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I have tried but it still doesn't work. Nothing appears in my Cloud Firestore

Comment: @ian12_ Does the user exist in `users` collection? If so, perhaps use `set` instead of `add`?

Comment: I have a collection created called `users` in Firestore Database but there's no users in there, that's why I wanted to get the data when they register. I've still tried both ways but nothing seems to work...